# Couldn't find Project with id=1 [WHERE "projects"."deleted_at" IS NULL]

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the paranoia gem.

I have a bunch of projects in my database but for somereason they are behaving as if they were deleted. When I navigate to my projects/1 route I get the error:

```
Couldn't find Project with id=1 [WHERE "projects"."deleted_at" IS NULL]
```

When I type this in my console:

```
Project.find(1).deleted_at
```

I get

```
nil
```

What is happening here?

This is my controller show action:

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @comments = Comment.all.where(:project_id => @project.id)
    @updates = ProjectUpdate.all.where(:project_id => @project.id)
end
```

Error happens on

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
```

Here are some model Project scopes:

```
scope :by_category, lambda {|category| {:conditions => {:category_id => category.id}}}
scope :by_npo, lambda {|npo| {:conditions => {:npo_id => npo.id}}}
```

With `Project.find(1)` I get:

```
=> #<Project id: 1, name: "project 1", npo_id: 1, description: "project1 description", location_id:
4, singular_unit: "1", past_tense_action: "past tense action", conversion: #<BigDecimal:7547d78,'0.1
5E1',18(45)>, created_at: "2014-05-13 00:12:33", updated_at: "2014-05-22 01:20:51", future_tense_act
ion: "future tense action", plural_unit: "2", amount1: #<BigDecimal:75475b0,'0.1E2',9(36)>, amount2:
 #<BigDecimal:7547520,'0.2E2',9(36)>, amount3: #<BigDecimal:7547490,'0.3E2',9(36)>, min_amount: nil,
 other_amount: true, short_description: "project1 short description", featured_image_id: 3, deleted_
at: nil>
```

From my index page I link to it 2ice(this is the relevant code:

```
    <div class="pj">

      <h5><%= link_to project.name, project, :class => "button-link" %> </h5>
      <hr />
      <div class="index_featured_image">
        <%= link_to image_tag(project.get_featured_image, :alt => "Project Title", class: "featured_image"), project %>
      </div>
      <div class="proj-content">
        <p><strong><%= link_to project.npo.name, npo_path(project.npo) %></strong></br>
        <%= project.short_description %></p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="project-loc"><i class="footicons fi-marker large"></i>  <%= project.location.city_state %></p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <%= button_tag :type => "button", :class => "radius" do %>
          <%= link_to "View More", project, :class => "button-link" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Good question - I suppose you're trying to show the `deleted_at` value?

Comment: Can you show the method/action of the controller url, you are hitting to the browser ?

Comment: Are you keeping track of the deleted records?

Comment: On which line did you get the error?

Comment: I have added my controller show action above. Also a collaborator installed the paranoia gem(https://github.com/radar/paranoia) not long ago. I've recently pulled and think this might be causing the problem

Comment: Updated questions with line with error

Comment: Can you post the `code` through which you are navigating to `projects/1`? I guess its  the `link_to`.

Comment: And also if you defined any `scopes` in `Project model`,then please post it too.

Comment: @pavan what do you mean? I have resources :projects in my config/routes

Comment: I have added some scopes, although that was done by a collaborator I have never used scopes before not sure what they might do

Comment: I mean how you are navigating to the `show page`? through the `link_to`? Then please post that code.

Comment: @pavan I added Project.find(1) database output to my questions. I am navigating in my local environment directly by putting http://localhost:3000/projects/1 on my browser

Comment: Can you post your index view page code?

Comment: @pavan done, do you have any idea of what might be causing this. This does not seem like a linking issue to me its more of a database problem with paranoia gem

Comment: Is that your full index view page code?

Comment: Could you try this on your console and what that output `Project.with_deleted.find(1)` ?

Comment: That is not my full index page, I have alot of other code in there, that is just the relevant part.

Comment: Please post your full index page

Comment: Project.with_deleted.find(1) returns my first Project

Comment: Could you change this `@project = Project.find(params[:id])` to `@project = Project.with_deleted.find(params[:id])` , and what the result appear, error or succes?

Comment: That might be a stupid question, but is your console running in the same environment as your server?

Comment: @BroiSatse hmmm how would I check?

Comment: @pavan not working, get same error as before... but its wierd, its the same exact error on the same line but it shows the old sytax on the error message. I tried restarting the server and new window everything but it still shows the old systax. And yes I did save the code change.. Not sure what is happening.

Comment: I was in a different directory than I should have damn........ I have 2 project by the same name somehow in different directories. Stupid mistake!

Comment: @user3597950 I think you should update your question to clarify that for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple guesses and some advice.
First the guesses. If `Project.find(params[:id])` calls `WHERE "projects"."deleted_at" IS NULL` condition on the table, there must be a `default_scope` call on the Project. Though it's still weird why id prevents the find method from finding the correct project, if it's really not deleted. Let me see that default_scope (or better just post the whole model in a gist) and I might tell a bit more.

Now some advice. It's not really related to the current issue, but I believe, it will make your Rails life a lot easier these days.

1. Try not to use deprecated syntax, get on with the new one. 
   E.g. those scope calls should look like this

   ```
   scope :by_category, ->(category){where(category_id: category.id)}
   ```
2. Don't use `.all` with `.where`. You just don't need it. The `.where` call will return an ActiveRecord::Relation object you are looking for.
3. Try to reduce the number of instance variables in controllers. For example you can omit the use of the `@comments` and `@updates` variables in your `show` action, provided that you have set the needed associations on the Project model.

   ```
   has_many :comments
   has_many :updates, class_name: ProjectUpdate
   ```

   Then in the view you can refer to them as @project.comments and @project.updates without the need to store them separately. It will clean up the controller a bit. Also, if you want to ensure that the comments and updates are not lazy-loaded, you can load them together with the project by calling `@project = Project.includes(:comments, :updates).find(params[:id])`.

Hope that would be helpful. I'll update the answer would I have something more concrete on the problem.

Comment: I was in the wrong directory... Thanks for your help though!